# Change language of URL on generateEmailVerificationLink() FirebaseAdmin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to change the language of the link that was generating the function generateEmailVerificationLink (), I tried admin.auth().LanguageCode = 'es', but it didn't work.

This is my code:

```
  // Function for creating to validation link with firebase admin
async getLinkForEmailVerification(email) {
    admin.auth().languageCode= 'es';
    const actionCodeSettings = {
        url: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
    };

    return admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email, actionCodeSettings).then((link) => link);
}
```

I'm using firebase admin with node.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Custom it by manually way - Appending `lang` parameter to the link:

```
async getLinkForEmailVerification(email) {
  const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
  };

  let link = await admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email, actionCodeSettings);
  link += '&lang=es'; // this line

  return link;
}
```